# Property 'gt' does not exist on type 'ZodEffects<ZodNumber, number, unknown>'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, zod

I am trying to use zod to preprocess String before coerce it into Number.

```
const serviceCostSchema = z
  .preprocess((val) => Number(String(val).replace(/^0(\d+)/, "$1")), z.number())
  .gt(0, { message: "Service cost must be greater or equal to zero." });
```

I received this error

```
Property 'gt' does not exist on type 'ZodEffects<ZodNumber, number, unknown>'.ts(2339)
```

How should I re-write to get what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't chain off of the return value of `preprocess`. Instead, just add that to the schema that you pass in as the second argument:

```
const serviceCostSchema = z.preprocess(
  (val) => Number(String(val).replace(/^0(\d+)/, "$1")),
  z.number().gt(0, {
    message: "Service cost must be greater or equal to zero."
  })
)
```